# After Refreshing Partial View, Ajax Reloads the Page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view in my Index.cshtml and have a list in my partial view. When I click the list item, it calls the **selectProj()** and alerts through ajax as Test. This is what I need. My problem is that there is a button in my list as Add new project. When I add a project, I reload the partial view. After reloading the partial view, when I click the list item, it alerts again but also refreshes index.cshtml but after refreshing the page it only alerts not refreshing. I don't want to refresh my index. I would ask for your opinions about how to avoid refreshing. Thank you so much for your answers!

My code block in Index.cshtml below;

```
<div id="projectListDiv">
      @Html.Partial("SelectProjectListPartialView", @Model)
</div>
```

My Partial View is like that...

```
@model Projact.Models.ViewModels.IndexViewModel

<div>
   <button id="collapsibleProjectBtn" class="collapsible">Select Project</button>
   <div class="content">
        <ul id="projectList">
        @{
           if (Model != null)
           {
             foreach (var project in Model.Projects)
                {
                    <li id="p_@project.Id"><a href="" onclick="selectProj(@project.Id, '@project.ProjectName.ToString()')">@project.ProjectName</a></li>
                }
            }
          }
          <li><button type="button">Add new project</button></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectProj = function (projectId, projectName) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDocuments","Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'projectId': projectId},
            type: 'GET',
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {                
                alert("Test");
            }
        });        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Johnny the problem is not the ajax call but the link triggering the ajax, I mean as your code is not preventing the default behaviour of the link it is navigating; that is why it seems to be refreshing the page.

Can you try?

```
<a href="" onclick="selectProj(event, @project.Id, '@project.ProjectName.ToString()')">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectProj = function (e, projectId, projectName) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDocuments","Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'projectId': projectId},
            type: 'GET',
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {                
                alert("Test");
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: With returning false still refreshes pages. Unfortunately, didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Johnny I changed the code I think this will make the trick

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I really appreciate it. I changed the element "a" to "span" and it worked. I also have had a problem before like this about button. I needed to add type="button" to button solve this problem. I solved but still, I don't know what causes the problem.